# String comparison not working

Tags: php, comparison, string-comparison

I am trying to change the output on something when a category ID equals a specific number.  For some reason this always returns false.  What am I missing?

```
<?php 
$ad_id = '#_CATEGORYID';
$id = 55;

if ($ad_id === $id ) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
?>
```

**EDIT**
Sorry should have clarified, #_CATEGORYID is a shortcode from another application that returns integers.  When `echo $ad_id` the value returned is 55.

Comment: because '#_CATEGORYID' can never = 55.

Comment: How can '#_CATEGORYID' ever be equal to 55?

Comment: Where is '#_CATEGORYID' supposed to come from?

Comment: What value do you get if you var_dump($ad_id); just before your if block?

Comment: var_dump gives me string(12) "55"

Comment: @RonnieT - So you probably can't compare server-side.  Is the 'other application' interpreting the code just before output to the response maybe?  If that's the case, you'll have to figure out how to interpret / eval this markup before your comparison.

Comment: Have you tried $id ="55"? That 'string(12)' is suspicious too. There are unprintable characters in that string. Putting full information in your question would have helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you may need to eval your third-party markup before the comparison.

```
<?php  
eval("\$ad_id = '#_CATEGORYID'"); 
$id = "55"; 

if ($ad_id === $id ) { 
    echo 'true'; 
} else { 
    echo 'false'; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Even if he does that he is comparing "55" to "#_CATEGORYID", they do not equate.

Comment: Crap!  I was thinking that "#_CATEGORYID" was some kind of php lingo similar to ColdFusion's #myvar# markup.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ColdFusion, maybe you're right, I'd have thought the OP would have mentioned it or tagged it though.

Comment: HA!  So I was (nearly) right.  The pound sign is markup from another type of app/language, but not php markup.

Comment: yes, I was commenting on your answer to say so when you deleted it.

Comment: @vascowhite - I find it easier to delete the answer to work on it, otherwise I get a ton of comments about the old answer before I can post the new answer.

Comment: Me too, I thought that may have been the case. Well spotted.